# How to update dropdown with JSON value from AJAX call using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

Hi I am receiving a JSON list in the Ajax success block and I want to assign these values to a dropdown list potentialFailureModeList present on my JSP. I am new to JSON, i have tried a lot to findout on the net but did not get anything. Please help me. Any useful link will also work.

//Code from JSP

```
<td><select name="fmeaEntityForm[0].potentialFailureMode.id"
                            id="potentialFailureMode0" onchange="potentialFailureModeText(this)">
                                <option value="-1"><spring:message code="label.fmea.select.potentialFailureMode" /></option>
                                <c:forEach items="${potentialFailureModeList}" var="pfm">
                                    <option value="${pfm.id}">${pfm.potentialFailureMode}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                        <option value="0"><spring:message code="label.fmea.select.other" /></option>
                        </select></td>
```

//pattern receiving in ajax

```
{"potentialFailureModeList":[{"id":3,"potentialFailureMode":"potentialFailureMode1","remark":"1"},
             {"id":4,"potentialFailureMode":"potentialFailureMode2","remark":"2"}]}
```

//Ajax method
function getpotentialFailureModeList(elementIdIndex)  {

```
        if (-1 != document.getElementById("subSystem"+elementIdIndex+"").value)  {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/ISO26262/FmeaDocumentPage/potentialFailureModeList',
                data: ({subSystemId : $('#subSystem'+elementIdIndex+'').val() }),
                success: function(items) {
                    alert("success");
                    alert(items);
                    // to do task
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Error Received: ' + e);
                  },
            });
        } 
}
```

Comment: This can be done in a variety of ways - you should narrow this down to a more specific problem.

Comment: @FritzDuchardt I will be very thankful to you if you would provide me the links of the various existing methods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for replying. I got the answer. I am posting here, so that if anyone else need the same.

```
function getpotentialFailureModeList(elementIdIndex)  {

        if (-1 != document.getElementById("subSystem"+elementIdIndex+"").value)  {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/ISO26262/FmeaDocumentPage/potentialFailureModeList',
                data: ({subSystemId : $('#subSystem'+elementIdIndex+'').val() }),
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(items) {
                    var list = items;
                    $.each(list.potentialFailureModeList, function (index, item) {
                        $('#potentialFailureMode'+elementIdIndex+'').append($('<option>', {value: item.id, text: item.potentialFailureMode}));
                        })
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Error Received: ' + e);
                  },
            });
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

json should be in format of

```
 {id: x, value: y}
```

Then the ajax success function similar to this --

```
success: function (items) {
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
    $('#potentialFailureMode0').append($('<option>', {value: item.id, text: item.potentialFailureMode}));
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Is there any method to convert my received string into the format you have mentioned. Because in the format you have mentioned double quotes are not present on the attributes.

Comment: that i already corrected. but I am getting error in browser console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"potentialFailureModeList":[{"id":3,"potentialFailureMode":"potentialFailureMode1","remark":"1"},{"id":4,"potentialFailureMode":"potentialFailureMode2","remark":"2"}]}